# MVC Rotativa.ActionAsPdf generate Unauthorized in pdf

Tags: rotativa

Rotativa.ActionAsPdf is working fine when you have set Anonymous access true in IIS. but when you select window authentication , the Rotativa.ActionAsPdf Generate pdf with error Unauthorized etc.

google a lot could not find any solution ..

here is my solution :::

create a standard user name in your AD (Active directory) and use this user name and password to generate the file.

example

```
 string iFilename = "eForms_" + Id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_mm_yyyy_hh_mm_ss") + ".pdf";
        ViewBag.FileName = Server.MapPath("~" + "/Files/" + iFilename);
        var iResult = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("displayForm", new { Id = Id }) { FileName = iFilename, SaveOnServerPath = Server.MapPath("~" + "/Files/" + iFilename) };
        iResult.UserName = "genericuser";
        iResult.Password = "password";
        return iResult;
```